# Window Explorer can't be found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++-6

I'm using VC6 on XP system. I want to find a window whose title matches "C:\", but it can't be found. The return value of hr is -2147023116. Can anybody help?

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "C:\\");
IWebBrowserApp *pwba;
HWND hwndindex = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pwba->get_HWND((long*)hwndindex);
if (hwnd == hwndindex)
{
  BOOL found = true;
  blablabla...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the window title is exactly C:\ and not something like `Local Disk (C:)`? Use Spy++ to confirm. See [this screenshot](http://winsupersite.com/site-files/winsupersite.com/files/archive/winsupersite.com/content/content/128013/showcase/xpsp2_slip_01.jpg) for an example of Windows Explorer displaying C:\ drive, the title is not C:\

Comment: If that's the actual code I'm surprised it even runs, as you for starters don't initialize the `pwba` pointer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It's not actual code of course. I just posted what I think is useful.

Comment: @ta.speot.is But I tried some other folder path. Can't be found neither

Answer (score 2):

below code should work:

```
INT iIndex = 1;
HWND hwnd = ::GetWindow( ::GetDesktopWindow(), GW_CHILD | GW_HWNDFIRST );
while( hwnd ) {
  CString sCaption; 
  ::GetWindowText(hwnd, sCaption.GetBuffer(256), 255);
  sCaption.ReleaseBuffer();

  //DWORD dwProcessID = 0L;
  //::GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessID);   

  //CString sExePath;
  //::GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)dwProcessID, sExePath.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH), MAX_PATH);
  //sExePath.ReleaseBuffer();

  if ( sCaption.Find(_T("c:\\")) != -1 ) {  
        // found you!
  }

  hwnd = ::GetWindow( hwnd, GW_HWNDNEXT );
}
```

Comment: I added your code. But it keeps finding the first window, even though its caption is not "c:\\".  BTW, what is iIndex for?

Comment: iindex is not needed, you can use Spy++ to check where your window actually is

Answer (score 0):

```
HRESULT hr = pwba->get_HWND((long*)&hwndindex);
```

Problem solved! I missed one important "&"